# Understanding "TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable" in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use the code below to find the shortest path between 2 points and by doing so I am attempting to apply the Dijkstra's algorithm. For some reason the code is erroring out I was wondering if someone could have a look.
Any help is appreciated

Error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/calcdistance.py", line 86, in minDist
if distArray[v] < min and vistSet[v] == False:
```

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Python Code:

```
import sys
import csv

size = 100
class CalcCreate:
    locationList = []
    def __init__(self, size):

        self.V = size
        self.locationList = [] #Square brackets are an indexing operator
        self.distArray = [0 for i in range(size)]
        self.vistSet = [0 for i in range(size)]
        self.matrix = [[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range (size)]
        self.points = []
        self.readData()
        self.storeDist()
        self.INF = 1000000
        
        

    def readData(self):
        with open('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/Locations.csv') as f:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
            index = 0
            next(csv_reader)
            for line in csv_reader:

               pointName = line[0]
               x = line[1]
               y = line[2]
               number = line[3]
               edge = line[4]
               
               water=False
               if line[5] == "W":
                   water=True
                
               self.locationList.append( [pointName,  x, y, number, edge, water] ) # etc
               
               if not pointName in self.points:
                   self.points.append(pointName)
               index += 1 
        f.close()

    def storeDist(self):
        for index in range(0, len(self.locationList)-1):

            if self.locationList[index][4] !="":
                start = self.locationList[index][0]
                end = self.locationList[index][4]

                for indexA in range(0, len(self.points)-1):
                    if self.points[indexA] == start:
                        indexPointA = indexA

                        for indexB in range(0, len(self.points)-1):
                            if self.points[indexB] == end:
                                indexPointB =indexB
                                distance = self.computeDist(start, end)
                                break
                        break

    def computeDist (self, a, b):
        
        # provide the distance between two points a and b on a path. Assume adjacent
        distance=0
        return distance

    def dijkstra(self, srcsize):
        for i in range(self.V):
            self.distArray[i] = self.INF
            self.vistSet = False
        self.distArray[srcsize] = 0
        
        for i in range(self.V):
            u = self.minDist(self.distArray, self.vistSet)
            self.vistSet[u] = True
            for v in range(self.V):
                if self.matrix[u][v] > 0 and self.vistSet[v] == False and self.distArray[v] > self.distArray[u] + self.matrix[u][v]: 
                        self.distArray[v] = self.distArray[u] + self.matrix[u][v] 
        self.printSolution(self.distArray)

    def minDist(self, distArray, vistSet):
        min = self.INF
        for v in range(self.V):
            if distArray[v] < min and vistSet[v] == False:
                min = distArray[v]
                min_index = v
        return min_index

    def printSolution(self, distArray):
        print("Node \tDistance from 0")
        for i in range(self.V):
            print (i, "\t", distArray[i])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cc = CalcCreate(100)
    print(cc.locationList)
    
    cc.graph = cc.locationList
    cc.dijkstra(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `dijkstra` function, the line `self.vistSet = False` appears to be missing any indexing, so it replaces the entire `vistSet` with the boolean `False` instead of setting the elements of the list to `False` as you probably meant to do.